# eclipse 3.6.2 download cant open folder

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I am trying to download the Eclipse classic into my windows machine.(Version 3.6.2 for Win 32 bit). When i try to open the unzipped folder, it gives out an error "cannot open folder".
I think it is the problem with unzipping. I tried to download it thrice but still get the same error. Can someone help me out with this issue?I am downloading this as the first step of installing Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check the downloaded file size against the file size specified [on the download site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Is it the same? If it's different your download may be corrupt.

If it is the same - did you try to unzip, or just open it?

Comment: yes i downloaded and unzipped. After that when i try to open the folder, it gives out an alert saying the folder cannot be opened.